# What's the difference between Primary Selection and Clipboard Buffer?

Tags: x11, clipboard

I am tweaking in Webkit-browser land in **Linux** and I come accross the terms "*Primary Selection*" and "*Clipboard selection or buffer*" very often.

- I want to understand what are they and what difference do they have?
- Where does drag and drop pasting fit in?
- What is the job of `xclip` in this matter exactly?

Comment: Why have a single coherent clipboard when you could have two of them? </sarcasm>

Comment: @LatinSuD why have _only_ one when you could have two (or more)? it can be extremely useful.

Comment: Except it isnt. it's a right royal PITA when using gui and terminals.

Answer (score 50):

They are part of *Selection Atoms*, or *X Atoms*.

The *Inter-Client Communication Conventions Manual* for X states:

> There can be an arbitrary number of selections, each named by an atom. To conform with the inter-client conventions, however, clients need deal with only these three selections:
>
> - PRIMARY
> - SECONDARY
> - CLIPBOARD

In short:

- **PRIMARY** selection is typically used by e.g. terminals when selecting text and pasting it by pressing middle mouse button. As in *selected text is in Primary Clipboard* without any *explicit* copy action taking place. Quick-Copy is a good name for it. (Not limited to terminal emulators, but as an example.)
- **CLIPBOARD** is primarily used in connection with *MS Windows-style* clipboard operations. Select+Copy. The data resides in the *buffer*.

[Read more here.](http://tronche.com/gui/x/icccm/sec-2.html#s-2.6.1)

Support for PRIMARY was [added to WebKit back in 2008](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=17267).

`xclip`, which is a command line interface (tool) for X selections (clipboard), traditionally adds data to Primary Clipboard. Optionally one can choose which one to use by the `-clipboard` option given argument of either.

---

Corr.: Drag And Drop resides under [Xdnd.](http://www.newplanetsoftware.com/xdnd/) There is also a Wikipedia entry on the [spec](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_selection#XDND). It uses *XdndSelection* and should not interfere with PRIMARY.

The protocol is at least implemented by Qt and GTK.

Comment: CLIPBOARD is primarily used in connection with MS Windows-style clipboard operations. Select+Copy. The data resides in the buffer.  We just talking about this in linux nowhere else

Comment: @r004: What I meant is it is a *MS Windows* like clipboard (they work close to identically, including, (often), shortcuts etc.)

Comment: … for end-user, that is.

Comment: What about SECONDARY?

Comment: @emisilva: That is secondary (pun indented.) Nah. (Unfortunately) seldom used. If you want something more beyond the links in answer, perhaps a quick dive into [Charles Lindsey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_H._Lindsey)'s fight for [the secondary selection](http://www.cs.man.ac.uk/~chl/secondary-selection.html) is to the liking  :) You could also test with [Emacs](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Secondary-Selection.html) – but your WindowManager would likely mess things up ...

Answer (score 5):

FWIW, on Debian (Kali), here is how the different selections correspond to the various 'paste options':

```bash
echo primary | xclip -sel p
echo secondary | xclip -sel s
echo clipboard | xclip -sel c

# Ctrl + Shift + v: clipboard
# Middle click: primary
# Paste selection: (Shift + Insert): primary

# with the -o option, xclip outputs the specified "selection"
# to stdout:

xclip -o -sel p
# stdout output: "primary"

xclip -o -sel s
# stdout output: "secondary"

xclip -o -sel c
# stdout output: "clipboard"
```

In my case I performed this in a VMWare VM. The selection which the host OS uses/sees/receives from is primary.

If you dont care to use multiple selections, you can alias xclip to use both primary and clipboard selections like so:

[image: xclip]

Comment: Why you are using screenshots for code?