# Configure Cygwin so that Windows's Shift+Insert pastes into xterm

Tags: x11, clipboard

I had Cygwin and its X-Windows installed on my Windows 10 laptop.  On
all of my Windows computers (Acer, EliteBook, some Dell brand, and
others), the Windows 10 and X-Windows clipboard buffers were common
(or somehow made to behave as if they were common).
[Here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/139191) is a
description of the two buffers.

I recently had to duplicate this Cygwin setup.  My workhorse EliteBook
(840 G6) started to show keyboard circuit problems, so I was lucky
enough to get a replacement EliteBook 650 G9.  They differ in physical
form factor, but software-wise, they are more similar than any other
two laptops that I've ever used.  It was simple to replicate the
Cygwin environment using
[this](https://gist.github.com/erikvip/63b236078d4ff4163fd3?permalink_comment_id=4661713#gistcomment-4661713)
package list migration procedure, although the package versions
themselves would be the most recent available (presumably!).

Since the computers are very similar, as are the Cygwin packages, I
would expect very similar behaviour.  However, when I use Cygwin to
put text into the copy/paste buffer, it *cannot* be pasted in a Cygwin
xterm using `Shift+Ins`.  Instead, I need to issue a
middle-mouse-button click (which I emulate in Windows 10 with a
3-finger tap).

While this does not work on the new EliteBook 650 G9, it *did* work on
my various past laptops, including the EliteBook 640 G6.  Even on the
new EliteBook 650 G9, it `Shift-Ins` *does* work on a Cygwin mintty (the
default terminal that is launched for Bash).  **How can I get
`Shift+Ins` to paste into xterm?**

## Troubleshooting

`Shift+Ins` doesn't paste into an xterm in the new EliteBook 650 G9
regardless of *how* I put text into the Primary or Clipboard buffers,
including the following:

- Highlight in a Windows 10 window and press Ctrl+C
- Highlight in a Cygwin mintty terminal
- Highlight in a Cygwin mintty terminal and press <Return> (which
  copies from a CMD terminal window)
- Using Gvim to yank into register `*` (Primary selection buffer)
- Using Gvim to yank into register `+` (Clipboard buffer)
- In a CMD terminal window, highlight text and press
- In an xterm, select some text

In all of the above, the emulated middle-mouse-button click *does*
paste into the xterm with the exception of Gvim yanking into
register `+`; the latter doesn't seem to update the Primary selection
buffer.  All of the above also seems to paste into the Cygwin mintty
terminal using `Shift+Ins`, and into Windows notepad using `Shift+Ins`
*and* `Ctrl+V`.

I confirmed proper functionality of the `Shift+Ins` not just in
Cygwin's mintty terminal, but also in Windows's Notepad.  It pastes
text placed into Cygwins Primary selection and Clipboard buffers.

[This](https://x.cygwin.com/docs/ug/using-clipboard-integration.html)
Cygwin X-Windows page shows that the two buffers are supposed to be
integrated by default.  I confirmed that the checkbox for *Clipboard
may use PRIMARY selection* is enabled.  My ~/.Xresources files is
identical on both EliteBooks, and I have nothing in there pertaining
to clipboards (just fonts and colour).

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Business-Notebooks/There-is-no-INSERT-key-on-the-new-2018-Hp-840-elitebook-G5/m-p/6802320/highlight/true#M152044) posted answer to the absence of an Insert key on HP EliteBooks, `Fn+E` generates an `Ins` keystroke.  It only works for those EliteBooks that are designed to generate an `Ins` keystroke in response to that combination of key presses.  It works on both my dying 840 G6 and my 650 G9.

It is, however, a bit more complicated than described because it's not obvious how to effect the depression of the `Fn` key.  Apparently, you don't just hold down the key marked `Fn`.  Rather, you hold down the `CapsLock` key *first*, then hold down the `Fn` key.  Only then do you press the `E` key to paste: `CapsLock`+`Fn`+`E`.

xterm responds to this as if the middle mouse button is pressed, pasting whatever text is in the Primary Selection.  Since the Primary Selection is supposed to be synchronized to the Clipboard Buffer by Cygwin, we can just think of simply as "pasting" (or at least, we can now, with the discovery of how to effect a `Shift+Ins` paste).

What this tells me is that the following input events are intercepted / received at different levels, sometimes at the application level, and conditionally mapped to each other:

- `Ctrl`+`V`
- Middle mouse button click
- `CapsLock`+`Fn`+`E`
- `Shift`+`Ins[ert]`

The dependency on the application is clear from these facts: (i) `Ctrl`+`V` only pastes for Windows apps; (ii) Middle-mouse button click only pastes for Cygwin apps (mintty and xterm); (iii) `CapsLock`+`Fn`+`E` pastes for Windows, Cygwin, and Cygwin X-Windows apps; and (iv) `Shift`+`Ins[ert]` pastes for Cygwin's mintty terminal and Windows apps, but not xterm (and possibly not for X-Windows in general).  The last caveat about not working for xterm seems furthermore to be installation dependent, as this is the first laptop for which `Shift`+`Ins[ert]` does not work.

For laptops that have an actual `Shift`+`Ins[ert]` key, such as my new EliteBook 650 G9, `CapsLock`+`Fn`+`E` is a *different* key combination.  It can therefore be very confusing to say that the latter "is" `Shift`+`Ins[ert]`.  For clarity, I suggest that any discussion of `CapsLock`+`Fn`+`E` refer to that key combination as a *synthetic* `Shift`+`Ins[ert]` in order to distinguish it from the *actual* depression of the physical `Shift`+`Ins[ert]` keys that are present on the keyboard.

If `Shift`+`Fn`+`E` isn't a solution for you, another potential solution is [this](https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Hardware-and-Upgrade-Questions/Revisit-There-is-no-INSERT-key-on-the-new-2018-Hp-840/m-p/7777566#M597467) use of "SharpKeys" to remap an otherwise unused key to the desired `Shift+Ins`.